# For-looping through the indices of rows in a particular column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
technologies = ({
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","pandas","Oracle","Java"],
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,26000,22000,24000,21000,22000],
    'Duration':['30day', '40days' ,'35days', '40days', '60days', '50days', '55days']
              })
df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)
print(df)

   Courses    Fee Duration
0    Spark  20000    30day
1  PySpark  25000   40days
2   Hadoop  26000   35days
3   Python  22000   40days`
4   pandas  24000   60days
5   Oracle  21000   50days
6     Java  22000   55days
```

I need to run a for loop for a different problem, in which I need to extract the Duration from this dataframe at each row corresponding to the index.

For example, I want something like this:

```
for i in range(7):
   d = df[["Duration"]][i] #This should give me the value of the Duration at i^th row
   print(d)
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Index.get_loc` to convert `Duration` column to get its integer location:

```
for i in range(7):
    d = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Duration')]
    print(d)
```

Note: in your example you can use either `.iloc` or `.loc` because index labels and positions are the same.

Why use `df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Duration')]` vs `df.iloc[i]["Duration"]`?

```
>>> %timeit df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Duration')]
22.2 µs ± 1.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.iloc[i]["Duration"]
60.2 µs ± 122 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

And you slice your dataframe only once instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
for i in range(7):
   d = df.iloc[i]["Duration"]
   print(d)
```

Comment: I prefer this: `for i in df.index: print (df.loc[i, 'Duration'])` but I'm not convinced you need to iterate. Unfortunately we won't know since the actual problem you're trying to solve hasn't been mentioned here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use a for loop as mentioned. It is for another problem, this was just an MWE. In my original problem, I have multiple for loops and I need to import the rows according to the loop's iteration.